# How to toggle icon button properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi all I have one button with font-awesome icon. I want to toggle that icon using jQuery or Javacript anything would be fine. I tried jQuery but previous icon is not getting removed from the button new icon is gettig toggled. Here is the code-

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="share_screen_button" ng-click="share_screen()"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></button>
```

```
$scope.share_screen=async () => {
    if ( $scope.roomObject === undefined) return;
    if (screenShareObj === undefined) {
        screenShareObj = await $scope.roomObject.createScreenShareObject();
       
            $("#share_screen_button").removeClass("fas fa-desktop");
            $("#share_screen_button").addClass("far fa-window-close");

    } else {
        screenShareObj.leave();
        screenShareObj = undefined;

        $("#share_screen_button").removeClass("far fa-window-close");
        $("#share_screen_button").addClass("fas fa-desktop");
    }
}
```

How to resolve this? please help

Comment: Dollars are conflicting in your code.

Comment: @Teemu How it can be resolved ?

Comment: $scope in your code. are you using angularjs?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @ArunSharma yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Angularjs or any other framework please avoid direct manipulation as far as possible. let framework do it for you.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="share_screen_button" ng-click="toggle()">
    <i ng-class="{'fas fa-desktop':which_class,'far fa-window-close':!which_class}"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)
{
  $scope.which_class=true
  $scope.toggle = function()
  {
    $scope.which_class = !$scope.which_class
    console.log($scope.which_class)
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay Got it thanks a lot.